# CSS child element producing a margin the full width of parent

Tags: html, css

building an overlay containing a stylised container for some text, however this container seems to be producing a margin which when combined with the elements normal width takes up the entire parent element width. According to chrome dev tools its the `.flipcontainer`element that is causing this.

It's really weird behaviour and I can't figure out why its behaving in this way.

If I wanted to place content to the right of the container for example, I would not be able to because of this margin being produced.

```css
.flipcontainer {
  height: 230px;
  width: 150px;
}
.flipcalender {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  background: linear-gradient(white, #f4f2f2);
}
.mmouter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1.5px solid #dddddd;
}
.mmmiddle {
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
}
.mminner {
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, #f4f2f2);
  position: relative;
}
.mmbreaker {
  width: 99%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 115px;
}
#mmlightbox {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
  /* margin-right: 239px; */
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  border: solid 2px #f21c0a;
}
```

```html
<div id='mmlightbox'>
  <div class='flipcontainer'>
    <div class='flipcalender mmouter'>
      <div class='flipcalender mmmiddle'>
        <div class='flipcalender mminner'>
          <p class='daysremaining'></p>
          <p>days</p>
          <div class='mmbreaker'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding float: left removes this and you can add content next to it

```
.flipcontainer {
    height: 230px;
    width:150px;
    float: left;
}
```

See Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/epe3bfdw/

Comment: doh so simple, swear this was the first thing i tried but guess not, just been staring at it too long, thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: Happens to everyone :) Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

Add `float: right;` to `.flipcontainer` css like so:

```
.flipcontainer {
    height: 230px;
    width:150px;
    float: right;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/76rpyapa/)

The *margin* you saw was because you specified the *width* to '150px'.